# 'Boot space insufficient' Problem after updating Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, disk-usage

Recently, I updated my Ubuntu 16.04 and now I am facing problem with my boot space. How can I fix this problem? Is there any way to reallocate the `/boot` space?

[image: This picture shows the problem]

Comment: Have you tried to run `sudo apt autoremove` in a terminal, to remove unused packages, including old kernels ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but Will it affect my other dependent packages?

Comment: `autoremove` only removes the packages and dependencies which are not being used.

Comment: It will only remove autoinstalled packages there isn't needed anymore. It lists the packages it want to remove, so you have a chance to opt out if it looks wrong. Also `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` should suggest to run autoremove.

Comment: is your `/boot` a separate partion?

Comment: @KuntalMajumder `the volume "boot" .. ` it says. So Yes, boot is a separate partition.

Comment: @SorenA then even purging packages wont make any difference, I think..

Comment: I think using autoremove sometimes may kill desktop drivers also.

Comment: @KuntalMajumder; autoremove will also remove old kernels from /boot, so it will help.

Comment: @SorenA ohh well, cleaning the whole partition and then installing grub there can be a solution

Comment: Thanks @SorenA 'sudo apt-get autoremove' fixed my problem, without affecting other packages.

Comment: Make /boot larger